# How can I program the UIPageViewController to navigate through two separate views?

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I've asked this question before, and I haven't got any solid answers, I am determined to find the solution not take up too much time, so I added images through Google sites.

I'd like to navigate with Page Control from View 1 to view 2 which are 2 separate view controllers.

[pic one xcode](https://8c9963d0-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/todayingreece/home/Number1Help_03.png?attachauth=ANoY7crwgnmz0dmUdG6unBR5pvUV0tMx9wvH1LZZS8pnpk0JS_smk8V-pDjGE6L5Ti9Z6wqxpjf8D2XGVQQ7gdNXrxfEgQvvWVZL7Y7GR6tdhZSXpTX9GrWydXUU_ndr3OapKtYVJ45RLGLv9aTPny4M6oOLqQFD_-CCrrbhbvfwbe1vP_bQk9LheQg-ReJfQ8JIpPVmg4BECHbvQ_pH0hYVGNPROeec6wJHtwDxLyBcBhCfHm5Na4A=&attredirects=0)

[Pic 2 story board](https://8c9963d0-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/todayingreece/home/number2help_03.png?attachauth=ANoY7coaK3vxl3t7mwWmA6eQn-0RbV58Tffx_UfVOEmQsKJsq4j1N6EwYS1hWl7GYyjwxdceL2__C-9zTz5H4WtW3zcC3DLkladsFAxZ9V8CUBsfHHhQHBQmAV658WNKrOobT5-2I4OMYsjN_bXz4lqp3M6lMEm7o61GlUk2Sd0MFhQ-CbC9otjqe0M3xt-JfoaaplxTa493gt3qLrpuSUObkkYluVG2XnIwmZYEsS78PgKp6VFkpDU=&attredirects=0)

Additional code that needs fixing:

```
#pragma mark - Page View Controller Data Source

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController     viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
 {
    NSUInteger index = ((PageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

    if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)) {
        return nil;
    }

    index--;
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = ((PageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

    if (index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil;
    }

    index++;
    if (index == [self.pageTitles count]) {
        return nil;
    }
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
return [self.pageTitles count];
}

- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return 0;
}
```

I just need the UIPageViewController to navigate from view 1 to view 2 and back to view 1 from view 2.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have to use this method also

```
- (PageContentViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if (([self.pageTitles count] == 0) || (index >= [self.pageTitles count])) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    PageContentViewController *pageContentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageContentViewController"];
    //pageContentViewController.imageFile = self.pageImages[index];
    pageContentViewController.titleText = self.pageTitles[index];
    pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index;

    return pageContentViewController;
}
```

or refer this links hope it will work for you.

http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/

Thanks